# java: creating a method to operate on two objects (beginner)

Tags: java

I am a complete java/programming beginner and am trying to make a basic fighting game. As part of that goal I am trying to learn object orientation.

I have created a player class which currently has some variables (att, str etc, hitpoints) and am in the process of trying to make a strike() method. This method should take data from both players and perform a basic calculation on the hitpoints variable of 1 player object.

i think the strike() method should take two player objects (which I have defined in my main method) as input and specify the variables from each player in the body code, but i am not sure how to do this.

code:

```
public class Player {

  String name;
  int hitpoints = 250;
  int str = 10;
  int att = 10;
  int def = 10;

  public void strike(Player player)
  {
      hitpoints = hitpoints - str * att / def;
  }

}
```

Thanks for reading this far. I would be very grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sidenote : It is a convention in java that all class names should start with an upper-case letter

Comment: why is `strike` static?

Comment: Do you want to make the method instance instead of static so it can reference the `player` on which it's invoked?  Or pass both `player` instances to the method?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: There is no reason why the method is static. I will remove this now.

Comment: What does your interaction logic look like?  That would definitely help better define what your player class looks like.  On the flip side, you may not want to make the players responsible for knowing how to do damage to each other.  That should be the responsibility of an external class.

Comment: might be worth some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: thanks RC, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider what is actually happening here. One `Player` is striking. Another is being struck. I would implement separate methods for those two pieces:

```
public class Player {

  String name;
  private int hitPoints = 250;
  private int str = 10;
  private int att = 10;
  private int def = 10;

  public void strike(Player other){
    other.receiveStrike(str * att);
  }

  private void receiveStrike(int strikePower){
    int hitPoints = hitPoints - computeDamage(strikePower);
  }

  protected int computeDamage(int strikePower){
    return strikePower / this.def;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

    Player one = new Player();
    Player two = new Player();

    while (two.hitPoints > 0){
            one.strike(two);
            System.out.println("two's hitpoints: " + two.hitPoints);
    }
  }
}
```

So the `strike` method just tells the other `Player` how hard it was struck. That `Player` is responsible for determining how much damage the strike inflicted and updating its state appropriately.

There are a few keys to notice here. First, I didn't really add any code that you didn't already write. I just arranged it into methods differently. Second, the example code in `main` never calls that `receiveStrike` method. It just calls the public method `strike`. Also notice that the `Player` instance does not directly touch the `hitPoints` property of the player it strikes. The other player modifies its own `hitPoints` property when it is struck through the private `receiveStrike` method. That method uses the method `protected int computeDamage` to determine how much damage the strike will actually inflict. That allows us to do something like this:

```
public class InvinciblePlayer extends Player {
  @Override
  protected int computeDamage(int strikePower){
    System.out.println("Mwa-ha-ha-ha!!! I am invincible!!! ... Almost");
    return 0;
  }
}
```

You can strike `InvinciblePlayer` all you want and it won't do any damage at all. More generally, this allows a whole range of defensive abilities for different `Player` types. That's the real benefit of splitting the methods like this. The attacker determines how powerful the strike is and the defender determine how much damage it actually does.

That's just the tip of the iceberg of what you can do. I really wanted to stay as close to your original code as possible. One next step might be to create a type `Strike` and change `receiveStrike(int strikePower)` to `receiveStrike(Strike strike)`. That could players to respond differently to, say, `Kick` and `Punch`, or even to counter-strike certain attacks. That's a little advanced for now, but it's something to think about once you've grasped this.

Comment: what an incredibly detailed and generous explanation. Something like this goes well beyond what I expected. Unfortunately It seems that SO does not support direct user messaging, but perhaps (if you dont mind me asking more questions) I could continue here once I have implemented this and am looking at different player types/abilities. I am also very interested on the rest of the iceberg, and what you would have mentioned had you begun to deviate from the original code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your method only needs to take one player as an input parameter. If you don't make it `static`, a method already belongs to one object (a Player), so you only need to provide the other Player as an argument.

```
public void strike(Player otherPlayer)
{
   otherPlayer.setHitpoints(otherPlayer.getHitpoints() - str * att / def);
}
```

Note that you'll need to define `getHitpoints` and `setHitpoints` to access the other Player objects hitpoints, but this is a common Java convention. The `str`, `att`, and `def` variables all implicitly refer to those attributes of the current (`this`) Player.

Then you call it like this, so one Player strikes another.

```
Player a = new Player();
Player b = new Player();
a.strike(b);
```

Comment: Many thanks, somehow as as a complete beginner that answer seems very logical to me.

Answer (score 2):

> As part of that goal I am trying to learn object orientation.

Actually, you reason in a procedural way.

> i think the strike() method should take two player objects

Don't you think that `strike()` should be an instance method ?

When you write `myPlayer.strike(...)`, it is the object referenced by the `myPlayer` variable that will strike another `Player` object.
So using a method instance makes sense.
Keep the method as it is actually defined but without the `static` modifier.

Besides computing hit points should be also a `Player` instance method, for example : `computeHitPoints()`.

You could so write :

```
public void strike(Player otherPlayer){
      otherPlayer.hitpoints -= this.computeHitPoints();
      ...
}

public double computeHitPoints(){
  return str * att / def;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback. I don't understand "this.computeHitPoints()" but i will inform myself about it.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, the logic of the method was a fast/bad copy paste. I updated. The idea is that computing the hit points could also be extracted in a method. In this way, this makes the logic more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by litelite your class should start with an upper-case so Player.

Your function should then take a player object and alter the attributes of that object.

```
public void Strike(Player player){
   player.hitpoints = player.hitpoints - (str * att) / def;
}
```

I would suggest you follow this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this method would work, however, this class should not be "hard-coded" as it is now. Since str, att, and def are always going to be 10, then hitpoints would be set to 0. Your constructor should take values for str, att, and def and then initialize those fields in the constructor. Also, a minor thing you can change is using the -= operator. What you have in the strike method is correct (although I would not make it static) but you can instead write it like this:

hitpoints -= (str * att)/def

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand the question but did you try to do this ?

```
 public static void strike(player player1, player player2)
 {
  hitpoints = hitpoints - str * att / def;
 }
```

Please note the ClassName hint in the comments of your post and dont use a static method here

Answer (score 0):

As written in comments, your class name should begin with upper-case letter.
You can write your static method like this :

```
public static void strike(Player player1, Player player2)
  {
     player1.hitpoints = ... //access to variable 'hitpoints' of player1
     player2.hitpoints = ... //access to variable 'hitpoints' of player2
     int example = player2.hitpoints - player1.hitpoints; //kind of calcul you can do 
                                                          //with the use of your two players
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question, you should write a method in the player class that gets the properties or returns a copy (Getter/Producer) and performs the calculation and another that updates the internal state of the player (Setter). I would make the attributes private as well.